# nested for loop - Processing (java)

Tags: java, for-loop, processing, nested-loops

my task is to draw a grid of 10 x 10 wheels. Each should be a random color and have lots of spokes like a real wheel. I have to do this using nested for loops.

I have got to the code below but for some reason its drawing a 10 x infinite grid. I don't understand why as the outer loop should only run 10 times.

```
float XPos = 25;
float YPos = 25;
float Radius = 20;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            float RanR = random(250);
            float RanG = random(250);
            float RanB = random(250);

            stroke(RanR, RanG, RanB);
            ellipse(XPos, YPos, Radius * 2, Radius * 2);

            for (int j = 0; j < 360; j += 10) {
                stroke(RanR, RanG, RanB);
                line(XPos, 
                     YPos, 
                     XPos + Radius * sin(radians(j)), 
                     YPos + Radius * cos(radians(j))
                    );
            }

            XPos += Radius * 2;
        }

        XPos = 25;
        YPos += Radius * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show what does these methods `stroke` and `line` do? Also you have three nested `for`s so in a simple math you have 10*10*36 (360/10)

Comment: yes stroke determines the color of the lines. line draws the line. the inner for loop repeats 36 times to draw the spokes and when its finished it will move on to the next cirlce

Comment: I can't see why is printing infinite circles, maybe you should post all the code, but be careful, post only the code that you think be important

Comment: @JorgeCampos This is Processing, not strict Java. Those are not user-defined methods, but methods in the Processing API.

Comment: that is all the code, turns out the draw void was being done over and over which was making infinite rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks well, except that `draw` must be **reentrant**.
That is, upon being called a second time it should start drawing at the same position.

So (apart from the Radius), the fields should be kept local to the draw method.

```
void draw() {
    float XPos = 25;
    float YPos = 25;
    float Radius = 20;
```

In real GUIs the draw or paint method is called whenever the screen must be updated.

My guess: draw is called more than once.

BTW. Java convention is to use an initial small letter for fields, local variables, and methods: xPos, yPos, radius.

Comment: how is it called multiple times? because of `line` or `ellipse` function calls?

Comment: thanks u got it, i took out the void setup and void draw so the code only runs once and it gave me a 10 x 10 grid. thank alot

Comment: "Called directly after setup(), the draw() function continuously executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the program is stopped or noLoop() is called. " – https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html

Comment: This is not true. The `draw()` function does **not** have to be reentrant. It is one possible solution in this particular case, but Processing's `draw()` function does not have to be reentrant at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `draw()` function is automatically called 60 times per second. You're saving your `XPos` and `YPos` variables outside of the `draw()` function, so any changes you make to them inside your `draw()` function will persist the next time `draw()` is called.

Instead of saving your `XPos` and `YPos` variables at the top-level of the sketch, you could create them inside your for loop and base them off of `h` and `i`:

```
float Radius = 20;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      float XPos = 25+40*h;
      float YPos = 25+40*i;
      float RanR = random(250);
      float RanG = random(250);
      float RanB = random(250);

      stroke(RanR, RanG, RanB);
      ellipse(XPos, YPos, Radius * 2, Radius * 2);

      for (int j = 0; j < 360; j += 10) {
        stroke(RanR, RanG, RanB);
        line(XPos, 
        YPos, 
        XPos + Radius * sin(radians(j)), 
        YPos + Radius * cos(radians(j))
          );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that this will cause your circles to be redrawn in random colors 60 times per second. You could either use the [randomSeed()](https://processing.org/reference/randomSeed_.html) function to get the same random numbers each time, or you could call `noLoop()` at the end of `draw()` so that it's not automatically called again.

Comment: thanks that works too and is alot better. I would just have to remove the draw void so the code doesnt repeat

Comment: @Will That's probably not a very good idea. Use `noLoop()` instead.